# Importing ES6 module in LWC project (sfdx)

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components

Trying to do something relatively simple.
I've 2 LWC component under the lwc folder: **lwc/cmp1** and **lwc/cmp2**

How can I create a new ES6 module that will serve as a utils.js file and then import it to each of cmp1 and cmp2?

I tried creating the utils.js file on cmp1 folder but couldn't import it to cmp2. Tried creating a new folder under lwc folder but it still didn't work (can't import).

The error I keep on getting is:

```
force-app/main/default/lwc/utils/utils.js  LWC1011: Failed to resolve import "../utils/utils" from "cmp1.js". Please add "../utils/utils" file to the component folder.
```

There is no problem with the path given, VSCode easily find the related path and indicates no errors, only when trying to deploy to Salesforce

Comment: can you show relative code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should not use `"../utils/utils"` for imports from modules. It should be `'c/utils'`.

**Implementation:**

[Create utils module](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_javascript_share_code):

```
sfdx force:lightning:component:create --type lwc -n utils -d force-app/main/default/lwc
```

Delete `utils.html` file.

Put below code in `utils.js`:

```
// mortage.js
const getTermOptions = () => {
    return [
        { label: '20 years', value: 20 },
        { label: '25 years', value: 25 },
    ];
};

const calculateMonthlyPayment = (principal, years, rate) => {
    // Logic
};

export { getTermOptions, calculateMonthlyPayment };
```

Now deploy this module:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/lwc/utils
```

Now, in your component `cmp1` which is already created and deployed, import above utils module like below:

```
import { getTermOptions, calculateMonthlyPayment } from 'c/utils';
```

Now, you can use `getTermOptions()` inside the class of `cmp1.js` file.

Answer (score 5):

you need to create service component (component without *.html file).

Here is the example from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_javascript_share_code).

Your utils file.

```
// mortgage.js
const getTermOptions = () => {
    return [
        { label: '20 years', value: 20 },
        { label: '25 years', value: 25 },
    ];
};

const calculateMonthlyPayment = (principal, years, rate) => {
    // Logic
};

export { getTermOptions, calculateMonthlyPayment };
```

Your import statement in cmp1 or cmp2.

```
import { getTermOptions, calculateMonthlyPayment } from 'c/mortgage';
```

For more information follow LWC documentation provided earlier and [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) for import statements.

Hopefully, that will help.